# Typescript doesn't recognise declared modules (*.svg) from my declaration file

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Along other declarations, I've declared the following modules in my `./src/types.d.ts` file:

```
/// <reference types="@emotion/react/types/css-prop" />
import '@emotion/react';
import { PureComponent, SVGProps } from 'react';

declare module '*.svg' {
  export class ReactComponent extends PureComponent<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>> {}
}
declare module '*.ttf';
declare module '*.eot';
declare module '*.woff';
declare module '*.woff2';
```

When I run `tsc --noEmit` errors like ...

```
src/fonts/fonts.ts:39:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './pt-sans-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff' or its corresponding type declarations.

39 import PTSansregularWOFF from './pt-sans-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/fonts/fonts.ts:40:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './pt-sans-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff2' or its corresponding type declarations.

40 import PTSansregularWOFF2 from './pt-sans-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff2';
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/layouts/default/NavigationBar.tsx:4:41 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../images/brand.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.

4 import { ReactComponent as Brand } from '../../images/brand.svg';
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

... are spit out.

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./.gatsby/**/*", "./*.ts", "./plugins/**/*"],
  "files": ["./src/types.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "ES2017", "ES2019"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

My file tree looks like this:
[image: File tree]

How to make Typescript find my corresponding type declarations?

Interestingly the other parts of my `types.d.ts` have an effect, like when I define the interface `Theme` of `@emotion/react`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use it this way:

```
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.png';
declare module '*.woff2';
declare module '*.woff';
declare module '*.ttf';

declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');

  export const ReactComponent: React.SFC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

And then import it like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './svg/logo.svg';
import SomeImage from './images/background.png';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems like when `/// <reference types="@emotion/react/types/css-prop" />` is present, the types don't work. When I split up the declarations it started to work normally.

Comment: Very useful information, thank you!  You didn't even need a section for 'png', nor the 'title' for 'svg'.  I'm beginning to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I placed the following blurb in a `custom.d.ts` file in the project compile root directory to enable loading *svg* and *png* files-

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<
      SVGSVGElement
  > & { title?: string }>;

  const src: string;
  export default src;

}
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

However, I'm not expert enough to understand *what* exactly it is doing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems like when `/// <reference types="@emotion/react/types/css-prop" />` is present, the types don't work. When I split up the declarations it started to work normally.